# Issues on Win Host godaddy

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have simple mvc 4 application which tries to read data from a CSV file from server. When running on Local Host, it works fine. But when I uploaded app to
godaddy server, I am getting following error while trying to read the file

> System.TypeAccessException: Attempt by method
>   'DynamicClass.lambda_method(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure)'
>   to access type
>   'System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`2<CSVU.Models.DataTableEntry,System.Int32>'
>   failed. at lambda_method(Closure ) at
>   System.Linq.EnumerableExecutor`1.Execute() at
>   System.Linq.EnumerableQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[S](Expression
>   expression) at System.Linq.Queryable.Count[TSource](IQueryable`1
>   source) at PagedList.PagedList`1..ctor(IQueryable`1 superset, Int32
>   pageNumber, Int32 pageSize) at
>   PagedList.PagedList`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 superset, Int32 pageNumber,
>   Int32 pageSize) at
>   PagedList.PagedListExtensions.ToPagedList[T](IEnumerable`1 superset,
>   Int32 pageNumber, Int32 pageSize) at
>   CSVU.Controllers.FilesController.ViewCSVData(Int32 id, Nullable`1
>   page) in G:\Mayur Muley\Project\Caliber
>   Group\CSVU\CSVU\Controllers\FilesController.cs:line 200 at

There are many more lines of it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it resolved.. I dont know how but following are solutions I tried. Each solution must use its predecessor solution. For each solution I published app to godaddy with newer assemblies.

1. I tried signing my assembly.
2. When I was paging a list of my custom object. I wrote this code

> var temp = myPrevList.OrderBy(x=> x.IntegerColumn);
>   IPagedList listToSendToView = temp.ToPagedList(1,10);

Instead of this

> IPagedList listToSendToView = myPrevList.OrderBy(x=>
>   x.IntegerColumn).ToPagedList(1,10);

3. Then tried changing trust level by signing assembly with different key.
4. Then tried solution suggested by @[timothyclifford](https://stackoverflow.com/users/279204/timothyclifford) of implementing security roles, here I tried Level1. Published to godaddy. -> got no +ve results
5. Then tried Level2, same outcomes produced, no use.
6. Then tried None level, same outcomes produced, no use.
7. Finally I tried removing security rule set in step 4,5,6 and published and **MIRACLE...** **IT worked..!** I still don't know how and why it worked.

Thanks @timothyclifford.

Comment: No problems. Feel free to +1 anything you feel helped ;) Having a read of other StackOverflow questions, seems to be a lot related to GoDaddy and medium trust. Most people just suggest not hosting with GoDaddy...

Answer (score 1):

Reading https://github.com/troygoode/PagedList/issues/68

It sounds like GoDaddy have some legacy/weird security configurations.

Have you tried adding the following to your `AssemblyInfo.cs` file?

```
[assembly: SecurityRules(SecurityRuleSet.Level1)]
```

It may also be possible you're compiling to .NET4 but GoDaddy is .NET2, I would check this also to be sure.

More reading here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securityruleset(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I am trying what you have suggested.. 
Sry to ask this, But need to know why choose LEVEL1? what if I use level 2 Or None?

Comment: I tried all levels, i.e. level1, level2,none. It didn't worked. Kindly suggest any other solution.

Comment: GoDaddy defaults to medium trust, can you try changing this to a different level as described in https://www.godaddy.com/help/what-trust-level-can-i-use-when-running-aspnet-2531

Comment: Please see my answer how did I found a workaround with this. Thanks Your suggestion helped in some how.. I am not sure  that if it was because of setting security rule, hence not flagging your answer as correct one.. But thanks.